# If application is kept idle for long time then server side call fails

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, .net-core

We use OpenID Connect (OAuth 2.0) authentication.

If we keep application idle for 5 minutes and then perform any server call (post) then call happens but the object that get bound to server is null and thus get null exception error.

OpenID connect Settings:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options => {
  options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
  options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
  options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
 })
 .AddCookie()

 // Configure the OWIN pipeline to use OpenID Connect auth.
 // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-openid-connect-code
 .AddOpenIdConnect(options => {
  options.ClientId = azureAdConfig.ClientId;
  options.ClientSecret = azureAdConfig.ClientSecret;
  options.Authority = string.Format(azureAdConfig.AADInstance, azureAdConfig.Tenant);
  options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
  options.Resource = azureAdConfig.ResourceURI_Graph;

  // PostLogoutRedirectUri = Configuration["AzureAd:PostLogoutRedirectUri"],
  options.Events = new AuthEvents(azureAdConfig, connectionStringsConfig);
 });
```

Do I need to prompt user to refresh the application after certain amount of time?

Comment: It would appear so, but it entirely depends on why the calls are failing after the inactivity. I'd suggest implementing rolling authentication tokens if you don't want to have to detect auth expiration

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you please give some links about rolling authentication technique ?

Comment: How are you implementing OpenID Connect?

Comment: @ShyAgam Updated the question with configuration code

Comment: Did you try configuring DataProtection? Take a look at this: https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/issues/512

Comment: @ShyAgam yes i have used AddDataProtection